# Is there a way to specify certain geom_images to be placed on top in a dense scatterplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I'm using ggplot and gganimate to animate a scatterplot of college football teams. My audience specifically centers around one team, so I'm wondering if there's a way for me to ensure that that team is always on top, i.e. not buried under the other teams.

Source Code:

```
aB <- ggplot(cB, aes(x=PPP, y=C)) + 
  geom_image(image=cB$logo, asp = 16/9) +
  labs(y="Efficency (3rd and 4th Down Conversion Rate)", x="Explosiveness (Points per Play)",
       caption = "Figure: @stevenplai | Data: ESPN") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(size=70, face = "bold", family = "Helvetica"),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(size=60, family = "Helvetica"),
    axis.ticks = element_line(),
    axis.text = element_text(size=30),
    axis.title = element_text(size=40, family = "Helvetica"),
    plot.caption = element_text(size=30)
  ) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = mean(cB$PPP), linetype = "dashed", color = "#841617") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean(cB$C), linetype = "dashed", color = "#841617") +
  transition_states(Year,
                    transition_length = 2,
                    state_length = 3) +
  ease_aes('cubic-in-out') +
  ggtitle('FBS Offensive Factors - Explosiveness vs. Efficiency' ,
          subtitle = 'Season: {closest_state}')
```

[image: Here's a frame of the animation]

Comment: hi there, welcome to SO. Your questions sounds interesting, but its not reproducible. Are you using RStudio? Please install the `reprex` package which is then fully integrated into RStudio. This will help you create a reproducible example which we can work with (click 'addins' button and 'Render reprex'). Essentially, please create a sample data frame (in this case it should resemble cB). Make it as small as possible.

Comment: A trick I learned recently in case of bubble plots: Sort your dataframe before plotting in a way such that the team your focus is centered on is the last observation/row in the df. The team is then plotted last and so will be on top of all others.